# Run unit tests which fail during TFS-Build

Tags: unit-testing, tfs, automated-tests, tfsbuild

I have a huge amount of test cases running during the TFS-build process.

Is there a way to rerun all those test cases on my local machine which fail on tfs? Maybe via configuration or an extension?

My problem is that it takes quite a while to run all the tests again, so I would like to run just those which fail.
The second problem is, that the tfs build sometimes failes tests which are working locally. So I'd like to figure out which I really broke.

Answer (score 2):

I've never seen anything like this. I do think it would be possible to write a VS extension to pull the test results from TFS and create a test list file with all the failed tests and then load that in VS to rerun only the failed tests.

I wrote a simple extension and it wasn't that bad - http://dotnetcatch.com/2014/09/08/parameterizationpreview-visual-studio-extension/

Answer (score 1):

I've tried the exact same thing. However rerunning the tests locally didn't change anything, the tests still passed locally (even after >1000 tries) but failed sporadically on TFS. ( for that part I just put the tests in a for-loop ).

Check your log on TFS - or put it up here - the log should tell you what has failed in the tests and maybe a reconsideration/refactoring of the written failed tests should be made. Even though they pass locally doesn't mean they are right, if that makes sense. So check the log, rewrite tests and try again, would be my suggestion.